# Are there any risks involved in using Google SERP tracker services?

Tags: seo, google

Are there any risks in using a Google SERP tracking service?  I mean in terms of possible penalisation for the tracked site?  Probably not, but since Google seems to be getting terribly touchy about many things, I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a SERP checker is run, it usually doesn't tell Google what site it's looking for. It just does the search, returns the first 10 or so pages, then the SERP script looks for your site in the list of sites returned.

All Google would know is the terms being searched for. I SUPPOSE Google could figure out what site the SERP checks by process of elimination. Example:

A search for "baked goods" returns:
mysite.com
yoursite.com
stackexchange.com

A search for "cupcakes" returns:
mysite.com
yoursite.com

A search for "bread" returns:
stackexchange.com
yoursite.com

Since your site.com shows up on all the lists, perhaps it's the one that belongs to the person checking SERPs. But, it would be highly speculative on Google's part. Furthermore, your site may not show up for the targeted keywords... so that rules out THAT method.

It's a valid question, though, but I don't think Google cares about SERP checks. I gather they really care about their search results so they focus more manpower on their algorithm to weed out junk sites than monitoring individual sites.

Answer (score 4):

If you choose to use unauthorized rank checking programs (what's wrong with [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=34432&topic=8524)?) you are violating the Google Terms of Service:

> Don't use unauthorized computer
>   programs to submit pages, check
>   rankings, etc. Such programs consume
>   computing resources and violate our
>   Terms of Service. Google does not
>   recommend the use of products such as
>   WebPosition Gold™ that send automatic
>   or programmatic queries to Google.

[Google Webmaster Guidelines](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769)

At the very least, expect the rank checker's results to be unreliable - remember, Google offers [personalized search](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=https://www.google.com/psearch&nui=1&service=hist) (which your rank checker will not factor in).

Comment: +1 - was about to post this after reading Melanie's response.